# Using basemap breaks gridspec indexing

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to plot two sets of maps using gridspec, which format perfectly when I don't include basemaps, but once I do, the first image is displayed larger behind the other plots, and the grid starts with the second image and displays sequentially, leaving the last plot empty.

Plotted correctly (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgDJZ.jpg):

[image]

With basemaps included, plotted incorrectly (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jA9xW.jpg)

[image]

Here's my code that reproduces the problem, to see it working properly just comment out the m.drawcoastlines() line.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

outer_grid = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1, wspace=0.2, hspace=0.2)

#create plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
i=0

while i<2:
    inner_grid = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(3, 3, subplot_spec=outer_grid[i], wspace=0.0, hspace=0.0) 
    n=0
    while n<9:
        ax = plt.Subplot(fig, inner_grid[n])
        n=n+1
        m = Basemap(lat_0=0,lon_0=0)
        m.drawcoastlines()
        fig.add_subplot(ax)
    i=i+1

plt.suptitle('Gridspec/Basemap') 
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use `plt.Subplot`. Instead directly create the subplot while adding it

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(inner_grid[n])
```

While not strictly necessary it may help to add the axes as argument to `Basemap`; this may help remembering which axes is actually being used.

```
m = Basemap(lat_0=0,lon_0=0, ax=ax)
```

Complete code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

outer_grid = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1, wspace=0.2, hspace=0.2)

#create plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
i=0

while i<2:
    inner_grid = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(3, 3, subplot_spec=outer_grid[i], wspace=0.0, hspace=0.0) 
    n=0
    while n<9:
        ax = fig.add_subplot(inner_grid[n])
        n=n+1
        m = Basemap(lat_0=0,lon_0=0, ax=ax)
        m.drawcoastlines()

    i=i+1

plt.suptitle('Gridspec/Basemap') 
plt.show()
```

[image]